# Django trying to set up a project and find out which Django I have

Tags: python, django

I'm on a Mac OS X Snow Leopard with Python 2.6.5, I'm trying to get django working but I keep getting this error. Do I need to add it to the path? I'm not sure where django is installed is there any way that I can find it?

```
solidariti:~/home/solidariti  
→ python
Python 2.6.5 (r265:79063, Aug  8 2010, 21:45:26) 
[GCC 4.2.1 (Apple Inc. build 5659)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import django
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named django
>>> django.VERSION
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yeah, you need to add Django to your python path. I'm not sure where you have Django installed, but for what it's worth, I set things up so I don't have to remember. I use [virtualenv](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/virtualenv) and [pip](http://pip.openplans.org/). Create a new virtualenv, workon that virtualenv, and then

```
pip install django
```

pip and virtualenv are great for juggling python requirements. Django projects often have pip requirements files too, so if some day you want to use some [random Django project](http://code.google.com/p/django-crowdsourcing/), you can get the dependencies set up nice and quickly.

Answer (score 1):

This shows that there's definitely no Django in your Python include path.

You can try searching for the directory using regular file searching tools.